# How to add Pinyin diacritics programmatically in Google Apps Script?

Tags: string, google-apps-script, diacritics, cjk

I would like to write a function `dia`, which adds pynyin diacritics to provided characters, so that, forexample

```
dia('a', 1) == 'ā'
dia('a', 2) == 'á'
dia('a', 3) == 'ǎ'
dia('a', 4) == 'à'
```

and I don't want to hardcode all variants. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This JavaScript snippet works for me in a web browser; it implements the function `dia` that you described:

```js
function dia (char, toneNumber)
{
    const combiningDiacritics =
    [
        "\u0304", // COMBINING MACRON
        "\u0301", // COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
        "\u030C", // COMBINING CARON
        "\u0300"  // COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT
    ];
    if (/^[AEIOUÜaeiouü]$/.test (char) && ((toneNumber > 0) && (toneNumber <= combiningDiacritics.length)))
    {
        char += combiningDiacritics[toneNumber - 1];
        char = char.normalize ('NFC');
    }
    return char;
}
//
console.log (dia ('a', 1)); // -> 'ā'
console.log (dia ('a', 2)); // -> 'á'
console.log (dia ('a', 3)); // -> 'ǎ'
console.log (dia ('a', 4)); // -> 'à'
```

How it works:

1. Checks the validity of the character and the tone number.
2. Concatenates the appropriate combining diacritic mark to the character.
3. Normalizes the result to a composed form and returns it.

Comment: Please don't put two answers, as it is not clear which one is correct. If you have several solutions, group them in the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you don't want to hardcode all variants, but there are only 48 of them (6 x 2 x 4), after all... Since Google Apps Script appears to make use of *older* versions of JavaScript, you may have no choice anyway.

Here is an alternative JavaScript snippet which should work in a more universal way:

```js
function dia (char, toneNumber)
{
    var conversionTable =
    {
        "A": [ "Ā", "Á", "Ǎ", "À" ],
        "E": [ "Ē", "É", "Ě", "È" ],
        "I": [ "Ī", "Í", "Ǐ", "Ì" ],
        "O": [ "Ō", "Ó", "Ǒ", "Ò" ],
        "U": [ "Ū", "Ú", "Ǔ", "Ù" ],
        "Ü": [ "Ǖ", "Ǘ", "Ǚ", "Ǜ" ],
        "a": [ "ā", "á", "ǎ", "à" ],
        "e": [ "ē", "é", "ě", "è" ],
        "i": [ "ī", "í", "ǐ", "ì" ],
        "o": [ "ō", "ó", "ǒ", "ò" ],
        "u": [ "ū", "ú", "ǔ", "ù" ],
        "ü": [ "ǖ", "ǘ", "ǚ", "ǜ" ]
    };
    if ((char in conversionTable) && ((toneNumber > 0) && (toneNumber <= conversionTable[char].length)))
    {
        char = conversionTable[char][toneNumber - 1];
    }
    return char;
}
//
console.log (dia ('a', 1)); // -> 'ā'
console.log (dia ('a', 2)); // -> 'á'
console.log (dia ('a', 3)); // -> 'ǎ'
console.log (dia ('a', 4)); // -> 'à'
```